# Unable to fetch value from XML file where values passes as a key

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, bdd, qaf

#### QAF Version

> 2.1.13 and 2.1.14-RC1

I have below testdata  in xml file -

```
<registration>
    <existingdata>
        <title>Mr</title>
        <firstname>Narendra</firstname>
        <lastname>Rajput</lastname>
        <email>narendra.rajput@infostretch.com</email>
        <password>Qwerty@123</password>
        <confirmPassword>Qwerty@123</confirmPassword>
        <message>${registration.existing.user.message}</message>
    </existingdata>
</registration>
```

And the message's values is store in `appdata.en_GB` file -

```
registration.existing.user.message = There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account.
```

While I'm trying to access the message value in BDD step as given below -

```
Then verify user with same email already registered message '${registration.existingdata.message}'
```

Code implementation of the above step is -

```
@QAFTestStep(stepName = "verifyUserAlreadyRegisteredMessage", description = "verify user with same email already registered message {0}")
public void verifyUserAlreadyRegisteredMessage(String message) {
    verifyVisible("message.success.failure.text");
    verifyText("message.success.failure.text", message);
}
```

#### Expected behavior

Here I should be able to get the message value i.e.  **There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account.**

#### Actual behavior

But it is retrieving  the values as - **${registration.existing.user.message}** which is reference key in XML file

And this is how i have load the locales in `application.properties` file :

```
env.default.locale=en_GB
env.load.locales=en_GB
```

Note : If i'm running the test by passing in key then its working as expected as shown below

```
SCENARIO: UserRegistrationWithExistingEmail
META-DATA: {"description":"Registration with already registered email","groups":["REGRESSION"],"key":"registration.existingdata"}
    Given user is on homepage
    When clicks on create an account link
    And fill registration form with data '${args[0]}'
    And click on register button
    Then verify user with same email already registered message '${message}'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the local files are under configured resources. For instance if your resource configuration points to `resources` then local files must be under resources. Below are few examples:

```
env.resource=resources
resources.load.subdirs=1
env.default.locale=en_GB
env.load.locales=en_GB
```

all your resources will be loaded including locales from `resources` (and its subdirectories).

```
env.resource=resources\common;resources\qa1
#If you will set resources.load.subdirs=0 then resources from subdirectories will not loaded.
resources.load.subdirs=1
env.default.locale=en_GB
env.load.locales=en_GB
```

all your resources will be loaded including locales from `resources\common` (and its subdirectories) and `resources\qa1` (and its subdirectories). Keep in mind this will not load other resources under parent (in this case `resources`) directory.

Comment: I have same configuration what you have mentioned but no success. i have shown to @amit borania and he told me to raise issue for workaround

Comment: Where is your `appdata.en_GB` file and what you specified as value for `env.resource`?

Comment: `appdata.en_GB` is in `resources` folder and in application properties `env.resources=resources` set

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to upload the snap so i have commented on same issue on [github](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/issues/196). Let me know for further.

Comment: try with `qaf-2.1.14` release, it should works as above.